# Check if two dataframes have the same values in the column using .isin in koalas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, azure-databricks, spark-koalas

I am having a small issue in comparing two dataframes and the dataframes are detailed as below.
The dataframes detailed below are all in koalas.

```
import databricks.koalas as ks


mini_team_df_1 = ks.DataFrame(['0000340b'], columns = ['team_code'])

mini_receipt_df_2 = ks.DataFrame(['0000340b'], columns = ['team_code'])

mini_receipt_df_2['match_flag'] = mini_receipt_df_2['team_code'].isin(ks.DataFrame(mini_team_df_1))

mini_receipt_df_2
```

I am executing this code on databricks and I expect the `mini_receipt_df_2` should have the output as follows:

```
    team_code   match_flag

0   0000340b     True
```

But in my code shown above, the output is as follows:

```
    team_code   match_flag
0   0000340b     False
```

This makes no sense to me as using the .isin function would give me the `True` value for `team_code = 0000340b`     as this is the same in both dataframes.

May someone help me understand what is wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
mini_receipt_df_2['match_flag'] = np.isin(mini_team_df_1['team_code'].to_numpy(), mini_receipt_df_2['team_code'])
```

Output:

```
>>> mini_receipt_df_2
  team_code  match_flag
0  0000340b        True
```

Comment: The input dataframes are koalas dataframe, so I am not sure this will work in my case. Can you help me with a solution that works for koalas dfs?

Comment: What won't work about it?

Comment: I get this error message, ```PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead```

Comment: Okay, I see. Check the answer now. I came up with a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
mini_receipt_df_2.merge(mini_team_df_1,how='left',suffixes=[None,'_2'])\
    .assign(match_flag=True)

out:

  team_code  match_flag
0  0000340b        True
```